# Cannot send and receive any data from bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an simple sender/receiver android app based on bluetooth. Connection between two phone is succesfully created. But data is not sending and receiving.

Code what I tried :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView myLabel;
    EditText myTextbox;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;

    void findBT()
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                deviceName=deviceName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
                //String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                Log.i("## name : ",deviceName+" ");
                if(deviceName.equals("GalaxyTabAwithSPen")) {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // tel GalaxyTabAwithSPen
        // tablet GhhBbbGalaxyS

    }

    void openBT()
    {
        if(mmDevice==null)
            Log.i("test","notnull");
        ParcelUuid list[] = mmDevice.getUuids();
        for(ParcelUuid x: list){
            System.out.println(x.toString());
        }
        Log.i("size :"+list.length," "+list[1].toString());

        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(list[1].toString()); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        //UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        try {
            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            mmSocket.connect();
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
            beginListenForData();
            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.i("IO ex : ", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            myLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        Log.i("IO ex read " ,ex.getMessage());
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }

    void sendData() throws IOException
    {
        String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
        msg += "\n";
        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
    }
```

When I click open both tablet and mobile phone, myLabel text changed to "Blueetooth Opened" succesfully.

But when I try to send text to phone from tablet or to table from phone, nothing sended. Data listener is working. mmInputStream.available() always returns 0.

Some log details :

```
D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothSocket: connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[49]}
```

Comment: For a Bluetooth connection, one phone will have the role of the server (waiting for incoming connections) and the other one will have the role of the client (opening the connection to the server). In your code, I cannot see any traces of the server.

Comment: actually, my final goal is not connect with two phones. My goal is, control the app by this remote controller via bluetooth (https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12q.YQpXXXXcXXpXXq6xXFXXXl.jpg). So, how can I achieve this connection. I cannot install an app into this controller. I want just listen the bluetooth port for incoming data. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: I can't support you with this remote controller. I have no idea whether it works as server/device or client/central manager, whether it uses Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy and what protocol it uses. You are probably better off deleting this question and starting a new one without the confusion about what you want to achieve.